# Can't access properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, excel, xlsx

I'm reading a sheet using the SheetJS (xlsx) extension to read from the excel file file like so:

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file.path);
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
let sheet_json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
```

When I  run `console.log(sheet_json)` I get:

```
[
  {
    'Question*': 'Question 1',
    'Number of Choices*': 2,
    'Choice A*': 'Apple',
    'Choice B*': 'Pineapple',
    'Answer (A/B/C/D)*': 'A',
    'Correct Marking*': 1,
    'Negative marking*': 0
  },
  {
    'Question*': 'Question 2',
    'Number of Choices*': 3,
    'Choice A*': 'Car',
    'Choice B*': 'Bike',
    'Choice C': 'Truck',
    'Answer (A/B/C/D)*': 'C',
    'Correct Marking*': 1,
    'Negative marking*': 1
  }
]
```

Now I loop over the sheet_json array and I can't validate the properties, the result is like this:

```
// i is the index of iterator. o is the object iterated


   let sn = ["Question*", "Number of Choices*"]
   let props = Object.keys(sheet_json[i]);
   console.log(props); //===> false
   console.log(props.findIndex(o=>o==sn[1])) //===> false
   console.log(o.hasOwnProperty(sn[1])); //===> false
   console.log("Number of Choices*" in o); //===> false
   console.log(sn[1] in sheet_json[i]); //===> false
   console.log(props.includes(sn[1].trim().toString())); //===> false
   console.log(o["Number of Choices*"]); //===> undefined
   console.log(o[sn[1]]!==undefined);  //===> false
```

Why is everything showing up as undefined or false? Please help.

---

`node -v`: v13.14.0

`npm -v`: 6.14.4

`xlsx`: 0.16

---

Here's the excel file as well: [DOWNLOAD](https://gofile.io/d/RQ8QKk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replicating it here https://jsfiddle.net/t4ocdw67/.

```
sheet_json=[{...},{...}];
for(i in sheet_json)
{
    let o = sheet_json[i];
    let sn = ["Question*", "Number of Choices*"]
    .... //more code here
}
```

It seems to be working fine, there might be a problem with iteration part maybe

Comment: You haven't replicated it entirely. Please try to read it via sheetjs dependency, then it would be replicated entirely. 
Also using a plain JSON object is not creating the problem, converting a sheet to json creates a problem.

Comment: I tried it using sheetjs dependency. Converting a sheet to JSON is not exactly the problem, I believe the problem is with **encoding**. Our normal whitespace (UTF8: \x20) character is not equal to the whitespace (UTF8: \xc2\xa0) in the string by sheetjs conversion. To reproduce this you can copy text from terminal console and use [link](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode) to check and find different UTF8 encoding. Also this is why you can do all of this for any property with no spaces. You can use the props array derived from sheet_json with the same encoding.

Comment: Okay! That makes sense. But using toString() when creating a keys array also does not help. I'll try couple of utf-8 encoding modules and then report. Meanwhile if you do know the solution, you can post it here!

Comment: Created a new sheet (spaces were the issue), fixed the issue, checked it on the website you mentioned and you were right! The spaces between the words had different unicode characters.